# Custom validation not calling the passes() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to make a validation that will check whether at least one item is provided in an array  following the steps in [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)
Routes.php

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'bindings'])->group(function () {
  Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResources([
      'exam-papers/{examPaper}/questions' => ExamPaperQuestionsController::class
    ]);
  });
});
```

ValidateArrayElementRule.php

```php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ValidateArrayElementRule implements Rule
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //
  }

  public function passes($attribute, $value)
  {
    echo "there";
    return count($value) > 0;
  }

  public function message()
  {
    return 'At least one element is required!';
  }
}
```

ExamPaperQuestionsController.php

```php
 public function store(ExamPaperQuestionStoreRequest $request, ExamPaper $examPaper)
 {
    return response()->json([])->setStatusCode(201);
 }
```

In my test file I have

```
  public function error_422_if_no_questions_provided()
  {
    Permission::factory()->state(['name' => 'create exam paper question'])->create();
    $this->user->givePermissionTo('create exam paper question');
    $this->actingAs($this->user, 'api')
      ->postJson('/api/exam-papers/' . $this->examPaper->id . '/questions', [])
      ->assertStatus(422);

  }
```

ExamPaperQuestionStoreRequest.php

```
class ExamPaperQuestionStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
  /**
   * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function authorize()
  {
    return auth()->user()->can('create exam paper question');
  }

  /**
   * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    echo "HERE";
    return [
      'questions' => [new ValidateArrayElementRule],
      'questions.*.description' => 'required'
    ];
  }


}
```

The test is failing

> Expected status code 422 but received 201.

I can see the text "HERE" is logged but "there" is not. Why is my validation `passes()` function not being called?

Comment: can  you show output of dd($value); in passes

Comment: @JohnLobo no results for `dd($value)`. From code coverage results, the file is not even covered by the tests

Comment: any reason for not using default vlaidation   'questions' => ["required","array","min:1"]

Comment: @JohnLobo Nice! that actually works. but any particular reason why my approach is not working?

Comment: if you are not sending questions in request .I mean $request->all() empty then it wont call so you have to add required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose if your request contain empty then it wont call  custom validation. So you must add required filed to ensure request has key `questions`

```
'questions' => ["required",new ValidateArrayElementRule]
```

Incase questions is optional and if entered then at least two or three item required then you can use required if validation.

By default laravel support min in array

```
'questions' => ["required","array","min:1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use the simple method in validation? :

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|min:5|max:20',
    'detail' => 'required',
    'cat_image' => 'required',
]);
```